# Custom loss function: How to add hidden layer's output in loss function in keras with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer, loss-function, loss

In my model, the output of the hidden layer, namely 'encoded', has two channels (eg. shape: [none, 128, 128, 2]).  I hope to add SSIM between these two channels in loss function:

loss = ssim(input, output) + theta*ssim(encoded(channel1), encoded(channel2)).

How could I implement this? The following is the architecture of my model.

```
def structural_similarity_index(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 1 - tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_val=1.0) 
    return loss

def mymodel():
    input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))

    # encoder
    x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    encoded = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

    # decoder    
    x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

    autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)    
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss = structural_similarity_index)
    autoencoder.summary()        
    return autoencoder
```

I tried to define a 'loss_warper' function as shown below, but it didn't work. This is how I added this loss function:

```
autoencoder.add_loss(loss_wrapper(encoded[:,:,:,0],encoded[:,:,:,1])(input_img, decoded))
```

the 'loss_warper' function:

```
def loss_wrapper(CH1, CH2):
    def structural_similarity_index(y_true, y_pred):
        regweight = 0.01
        loss = 1 - tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_val=1.0)
        loss = loss + regweight*(1-tf.image.ssim(CH1, CH2, max_val=1.0))
        return loss
    return structural_similarity_index
```

The error message:

```
File "E:/Autoencoder.py", line 160, in trainprocess
    validation_data= (x_validate, x_validate))
...
ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:', array([...]...[...]))
```

Does anyone know how to implement this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered might due to how you added the additional loss function to your model. Instead of using add_loss() method, you can modify your custom loss function to directly include the SSIM calculation between the two channels. You may try the updated code below where the ssim_loss_encoded is calculated as the SSIM loss between channel1 and channel2 of the encoded tensor. Then, the combined_loss function combines the SSIM loss between y_true and y_pred with the ssim_loss_encoded using the specified weight theta:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ssim_loss = 1 - K.mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_val=1.0))
    return ssim_loss

def mymodel():
    input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))


# encoder
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoded = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

# decoder    
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

# Calculate SSIM loss between the two channels of 'encoded'
channel1 = encoded[:,:,:,0]
channel2 = encoded[:,:,:,1]
ssim_loss_encoded = 1 - K.mean(tf.image.ssim(channel1, channel2, max_val=1.0))

# Define the combined loss function
theta = 0.01
combined_loss = lambda y_true, y_pred: ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred) + theta * ssim_loss_encoded

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)    
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=combined_loss)
autoencoder.summary()        
return autoencoder
```